# What is alternative for DEF in jupyter cython

Tags: jupyter, cython

I am using `DEF` so that I can efficiently allocate arrays in Cython that I'm running in jupyter notebooks, like this (pointless) example:

```
%%cython
DEF iterations = 1000
def test():
    cdef int a[iterations]
    for i in range(iterations):
        a[i] = i
    return a
```

This gives a compiler warning:

> The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in-place literals instead.

I've read everything I can about that but I can't find a viable alternative to `DEF` that would allow static allocation of arrays in this fashion.  What are we supposed to do?

Comment: Probably do nothing and wait. I think the message with be removed from the next version because there isn't really a suitable alternative available that really does what you want. https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/ac390ce954297a52d537f0f3fb9d2aade296c951